# Set PYTHONPATH in Emacs on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, emacs, environment-variables

Emacs does not recognize my correct Python path. I think it is a general problem with Emacs not recognizing my environment variables. I have GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (i386-apple-darwin8.9.1, Carbon Version 1.6.0) of 2007-06-17 installed.

I have set `PYTHONPATH` in my `~/.bashrc`. Maybe I should set it somewhere else?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`.bashrc` only gets read when a shell starts; it won't affect Carbon Emacs. Instead, use `setenv` in your `.emacs`:

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "PATH_STRING_HERE")
```

You can set `PYTHONPATH` for the entire Mac OS session, by adding it to `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (more [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-113982)). You probably don't want to do this unless you have XCode (and its property list editor) installed.

([Via Procrastiblog](http://procrastiblog.com/2007/07/09/changing-your-path-in-emacs-compilation-mode/))

Answer (score 4):

In order not to manually copy paste:

```
(setenv "PYTHONPATH" (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL --login -c 'echo -n $PYTHONPATH'"))
```